# Will something terrible happen if my data points aren't independent?

Tags: regression, independence

Suppose I run a bunch of experiments, and get a bunch of datapoints, but several of the datapoints were derived from the same experiment.  (In the extreme case, I just repeat the same datapoint 10 times.)

Suppose I want to perform a statistical analysis on these datapoints, like a linear or logistic regression, or something more sophisticated.

How would the non-independence of data affect my analysis?  What steps would I have to take to correct for this effect?

Comment: Is your intent "how will my analysis be affected if I treat all the data as independent?"

Comment: Well suppose I plugged all the data into MATLAB or some other software tool.  (I don't know if these regression packages automatically treat the data as independent.)  How would that affect the conclusions I could draw?  What steps would I have to take to correct for this effect?

Comment: It depends on how you model your data! "Plugged the data into Matlab" doesn't suggest whether you use a model that would account for the dependence or not. Neither does saying "logistic regression". It depends specifically on how you choose to model it. If your model accounts for the dependence, then it may not be an issue at all. If it doesn't account for the dependence structure (i.e. you fit a model that assumes that the dependent values are independent), then there will be a number of issues - standard errors will be based on a false assumption, and tests and intervals affected

Comment: Basically I would create a matrix, with one row for each data point (even the ones that aren't independent).  And then I would use the standard regress() functions provided in some software package.  I'm not terribly familiar with statistics, but I imagine the software package would not know whether the data points were independent or not.

Comment: I guess the model would be something like $$\vec{y} = f(X\vec{\beta})$$

Comment: Yes, it sounds like you're modelling them as independent. More specifically, you could (even with that) still potentially account for the dependence via weighting, but it doesn't sound like you're doing that. Your model formula there describes only the mean (it should be of the form $E(y) = ...$ --- and it's the model for the variability/distribution about that which would account for such dependence).

Comment: So according to my advisor, it doesn't really matter if the points are not independent, as long as the training and test set suffer from the same problems.  This is highly unintuitive to me but whatever.

Comment: It really depends on what calculations you're doing and what properties that result from the assumptions that you're interested in. If you calculate the usual kind of confidence intervals, then for example, then I don't see how your supervisor's assertion would hold up.

Comment: On the other hand, if it's just point estimation you're interested in you may only lose some efficiency.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm just trying to train a classifier, and then use the classifier to make predictions.  Hmm, it kind of makes sense now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you model your data! "Plugged the data into Matlab" doesn't suggest whether you use a model that would account for the dependence or not. Neither does saying "logistic regression". It depends specifically on how you choose to model it. If your model accounts for the dependence, then it may not be an issue at all. If it doesn't account for the dependence structure (i.e. you fit a model that assumes that the dependent values are independent), then there will be a number of issues - standard errors will be based on a false assumption, and tests and intervals affected.

Comment: I've copied this comment by @Glen_b as a community wiki answer because the comment is, more or less, an answer to this question. We have a dramatic gap between answers and questions. At least part of the problem is that some questions are answered in comments: if comments which answered the question were answers instead, we would have fewer unanswered questions.